# Using a pointer to array

Tags: pointers, go

I'm having a little play with google's Go language, and I've run into something which is fairly basic in C but doesn't seem to be covered in the documentation I've seen so far

When I pass a pointer to a slice to a function, I presumed we'd have some way to access it as follows:

```
func conv(x []int, xlen int, h []int, hlen int, y *[]int)

    for i := 0; i<xlen; i++ {
        for j := 0; j<hlen; j++ {
            *y[i+j] += x[i]*h[j]
        }
    }
 }
```

But the Go compiler doesn't like this:

```
sean@spray:~/dev$ 8g broke.go
broke.go:8: invalid operation: y[i + j] (index of type *[]int)
```

Fair enough - it was just a guess. I have got a fairly straightforward workaround:

```
func conv(x []int, xlen int, h []int, hlen int, y_ *[]int) {
    y := *y_

    for i := 0; i<xlen; i++ {
        for j := 0; j<hlen; j++ {
            y[i+j] += x[i]*h[j]
        }
    }
}
```

But surely there's a better way. The annoying thing is that googling for info on Go isn't very useful as all sorts of C/C++/unrelated results appear for most search terms.

Comment: To ask a question about the Go language, tag it with `go`, more people will answer; Vatine did that for you. `golang` is an obsolete tag; as you can see there are 117 questions tagged as `go` and just 3 tagged, in error, as `golang`.

Comment: Note that you don't need xlen and hlen as arguments; you can use len(x) and len(h) instead.

Comment: just put `*y` to `()` => `(*y)[index]` and have fun, see [play ground](http://play.golang.org/p/eTg7wplH5c)

Answer (score 34):

**The Google Go docs [state the following about passing arrays](http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html#tmp_94) - they say you usually want to pass a slice (instead of a pointer?):**

### Updated:

As indicated by @Chickencha's comment, array slices are references which is why they are efficient for passing. Therefore likely you will want to use the slice mechanism instead of "raw" pointers.

From **Google Effective Go doc** http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices

> *Slices are reference types,*

---

### Original

It's under the heading

**An Interlude about Types**

> [...snip...]   When passing an array
>   to a function, you almost always want
>   to declare the formal parameter to be
>   a slice. When you call the function,
>   take the address of the array and Go
>   will create (efficiently) a slice
>   reference and pass that.

*Editor's note: This is no longer the case*

Using slices one can write this function (from sum.go):

```
09    func sum(a []int) int {   // returns an int
10        s := 0
11        for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
12            s += a[i]
13        }
14        return s
15    }
```

and invoke it like this:

```
19        s := sum(&[3]int{1,2,3})  // a slice of the array is passed to sum
```

---

Maybe pass the whole array as a slice instead. Google indicates Go deals efficiently with slices.  This is an alternate answer to the question but maybe it's a better way.

Comment: I agree that this sounds like the way to go. A slice is basically a pointer to an array already and is the preferred way of passing an array by reference.

Comment: Append doesn't work without asterisk. See [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qwWwoJqOC0)

Comment: @John K, even reference works like pointer, you can not mix them up. Your sample code to invoke function "sum" will not be compiled, as you can not pass a pointer to a function which needs a slice (reference).

The code to call function "sum" `s := sum(&[3]int{1,2,3}) ` can be changed to ` arr :=[3]int{1,2,3}
 s := sum(arr[:])
`

Full example can be found on the [playgroud](https://play.golang.org/p/3B7W2BVBfW)

Answer (score 22):

Types with empty `[]`, such as `[]int` are actually slices, not arrays. In Go, the size of an array is part of the type, so to actually have an array you would need to have something like `[16]int`, and the pointer to that would be `*[16]int`. So, what you are actually doing already is using slices, and the pointer to a slice, `*[]int`, is unnecessary as slices are already passed by reference.

<del>Also remember that you can easily pass a slice referring to the entire array with `&array` (as long as the element type of the slice matches that of the array).</del> (Not anymore.)

Example:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func sumPointerToArray(a *[8]int) (sum int) {
    for _, value := range *a { sum += value }
    return
}
func sumSlice (a []int) (sum int) {
    for _, value := range a { sum += value }
    return
}
func main() {
    array := [...]int{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
    slice := []int{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    fmt.Printf("sum arrray via pointer: %d\n", sumPointerToArray(&array))
    fmt.Printf("sum slice: %d\n", sumSlice(slice))
    slice = array[0:]
    fmt.Printf("sum array as slice: %d\n", sumSlice(slice))
}
```

**Edit**: Updated to reflect changes in Go since this was first posted.

Comment: Oh, as an additional note, the [...] notation for the length of an array can only be applied to array literals to make the compiler count the elements for you. One cannot, for example, have a *[...]int as the formal argument of a function.

Comment: O_o this doesn't work: cannot use &array (type *[8]int) as type []int in function argument

Comment: @Doug Interesting, it did compile when I posted it and old documentation also uses the `&array` syntax to pass an array as a slice. However, it doesn't work anymore, it seems.

Comment: @Doug Updated to compile with the current version of Go.

Comment: After messing around, turns out a []int still works, but you must manually convert the array into a slice when you pass the args (sumPointerToArray(array[:]) instead of just passing &array.

Answer (score 5):

The semicolon and the asterisk are added and removed.

> *y[i+j] += x[i]*h[j]

Is interpreted as

> (*y)[i+j] += x[i] * h[j];

*EDIT:* Please read the comments. The answer is probably no longer valid. and I haven't touched up on go for quite some time and can't even read this anymore.

Comment: In Go you can skip the semicolon, and the asterisk was how I thought a pointer to an array should be used.

Comment: Drop the semicolon. From Release 2009-12-22:

Since the last release there has been one large syntactic change to
the language, already discussed extensively on this list: semicolons
are now implied between statement-ending tokens and newline characters.
See http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/t/5ee32b588d10f2e9 for
details.

Comment: please please please fix the MD :) - looks like some alien glyph now haha (i wouldve changed it myself, but the edit queue is full for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

The length is part of the array's type, you can get length of an array by the len() built-in function. So you needn't pass the xlen, hlen arguments.

In Go, you can almost always use slice when passing array to a function. In this case, you don't need pointers.
Actually, you need not pass the y argument. It's the C's way to output array.

In Go style:

```
func conv(x, h []int) []int {
    y := make([]int, len(x)+len(h))
    for i, v := range x { 
        for j, u := range h { 
            y[i+j] = v * u 
        }   
    }   
    return y
}
```

Call the function:

```
conv(x[0:], h[0:])
```

Comment: The value of i is 0 to (len(x)-1) and the value of j is 0 to (len(h)-1). Therefore, the value of (i+j) is 0 to ((len(x)-1)+(len(h)-1)). Since array indices start at zero, don't we need ((len(x)-1)+(len(h)-1)+1) array elements for y?

Comment: For `var s []int`, the references `s`, `s[0:len(s)]`, and `s[0:]` are all the same thing, the slice `s`. So, more concisely, write `conv(x, h)`, instead of `conv(x[0:], h[0:])`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working Go program.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func conv(x, h []int) []int {
    y := make([]int, len(x)+len(h)-1)
    for i := 0; i < len(x); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(h); j++ {
            y[i+j] += x[i] * h[j]
        }
    }
    return y
}

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2}
    h := []int{7, 8, 9}
    y := conv(x, h)
    fmt.Println(len(y), y)
}
```

To avoid wrong guesses, read the Go documentation: [The Go Programming Language.](http://golang.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the other answers to this question talk about using slices instead of
array pointers but none answers how to solve the error, so I thought I would
write this answer. The error gives us a hint that it cannot access the index of
`y` because it is an invalid operation.

Your first approach is wrong as the Go compiler shouts at you. The problem in
the first approach is that `*y[i+j]` is wrong syntax. This is because
technically you are doing this `*(y[i+j])` and you can't just do that because
`y` in your case is a pointer to an int array. If you print `y` it would print
the memory address of the array.

You are trying to get the `i+j`th index of `y` which does not simply exist
because `y` is not an array. You can fix your code by adding parentheses to the
statement which would indicate that you are trying to get the `i+j`th index of
the array that `y` is pointing to. Use `(*y)[i+j]` instead of `*y[i+j]`. The
function would look like this after making the changes:

```golang
func conv(x []int, xlen int, h []int, hlen int, y *[]int) {
    for i := 0; i<xlen; i++ {
        for j := 0; j<hlen; j++ {
            (*y)[i+j] += x[i]*h[j]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code uses a pointer to a slice and not an array like your explanation implies

Comment: @Pizzalord oh yeah, sorry I by mistake used the word `array` instead of `slice` because the  question had by mistake used the word `array`. I'll replace the word `array` with `slice` in my answer but the code would work for both slices and arrays.