# In golang, how to embed on custom type?

Tags: go

I have custom types `Int64Array`, `Channel` and `ChannelList` like:

```
type Int64Array []int64

func (ia *Int64Array) Scan(src interface{}) error {
  rawArray := string(src.([]byte))
  if rawArray == "{}" {
    *ia = []int64{}
  } else {
    matches := pgArrayPat.FindStringSubmatch(rawArray)
    if len(matches) > 1 {
      for _, item := range strings.Split(matches[1], ",") {
        i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(item, 10, 64)
        *ia = append(*ia, i)
      }
    }
  }
  return nil
}

func (ia Int64Array) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
  var items []string
  for _, item := range ia {
    items = append(items, strconv.FormatInt(int64(item), 10))
  }
  return fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", strings.Join(items, ",")), nil
}

type Channel int64

type ChannelList []Channel
```

How can I embed `Int64Array` to `ChannelList` such that I can call `Scan` and `Value` methods on it? I tried the following:

```
type ChannelList []Channel {
    Int64Array
}
```

but I'm getting syntax error. What's important is to make sure `ChannelList` items are of type `Channel`, if this isn't possible via embedding I might just create stand-alone functions to be called by both `ChannelList` and `Int64Array`.

Answer (score 3):

An anonymous (or embedded field) is found in a struct (see [`struct` type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)), not in a type alias (or "[type declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)").

You cannot embed a type declaration within another type declaration.

Plus, as illustrated by the answers to "[Go: using a pointer to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2439453/6309)", you shouldn't be using pointers to slice, use directly the slice themselves ([passed by value](http://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value)).

[Wessie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243064/wessie) kindly points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702469/in-golang-how-to-embed-on-custom-type/27702577?noredirect=1#comment43822496_27702577) that `(ia *Int64Array) Scan()` uses pointer to a slice in order to mutate the underlying array referenced by said slice.
I would prefer returning another slice instead of mutating the existing one.
That being said, the [Golang Code Review](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Receiver_Type) does mention:

> If the receiver is a `struct`, `array` or `slice` and any of its elements is a pointer to something that might be mutating, prefer a pointer receiver, as it will make the intention more clear to the reader.

Comment: `Value` already passes normally, `Scan` requires a pointer because it **mutates** the slice with `append`. Your last paragraph is wrong, and it seems it has become a habit to just always include it when you see a pointer to a slice.

Comment: @Wessie agreed (answer edited). The name "Scan" has me confused. I didn't expect what would seem to be a read-only operation (`Scan`) to mutate anything on its receiver.