# Why are pointers used for struct instances in this golang tutorial?

Tags: pointers, go, slice

Making a simple api in golang, why does [this](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5635) tutorial use

```
var movies = map[string]*Movie{
    "tt0076759": &Movie{Title: "Star Wars: A New Hope", Rating: "8.7", Year: "1977"},
    "tt0082971": &Movie{Title: "Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark", Rating: "8.6", Year: "1981"},
}
```

while [this other tutorial](http://thenewstack.io/make-a-restful-json-api-go/) uses something more like:

```
type Movies []Movie
var movies Movies
movies = append(movies, Movie{id: "tt0076759", Title: "Star Wars: A New Hope", Rating: "8.7", Year: "1977"})
```

It seems like the first one gives me a map containing key value pairs where the value is a pointer to a movie. And the second one gives me an array(slice?) of movies where the id serves as the key for lookup. Why are pointers used in the first one?

Comment: "Why are pointers used in the first one?" Because the author choose to do so.

Comment: I dont see any particular reasoning

Comment: All i can see here is a slight advntage with respect to cache coherence . Using the struct as such in the slice would be good as there would be required data in sequence. Spatial locality is important in optimising cache usage,  this refers to placing related data close to eachother.

Comment: One thing that he isn't doing, but _could_ do, that would require a pointer in the first example is updating the struct fields.  You can't alter the struct fields of objects stored in a map without an intermediate variable (because they are not addressable), but you _can_ if the struct is stored in the map by pointer instead: http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/index.html#map_value_field_update.  This restriction does not apply to slices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand what pointer is used for. When you want to **share** the value use Pointer as the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1)

> A pointer holds the memory address of a value

As the first tutorial because they wanted to create variable that share value so it uses less memory.

As the second tutorial you don't need to add pointer variable to a slice.
Because Slice it self is a reference type.

> Slices hold references to an underlying array, and if you assign one
>   slice to another, both refer to the same array.

some reference : 
https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441112/2652524

Comment: Not answering the question

Comment: I wanted to help him to understand the usage of pointer in slice. and why we need to use it in map. maybe this is just an opinion. but I hope my answer help him

Answer (score 0):

I glanced through the article and I can't see any particular reason. Perhaps he's implemented something that wasn't covered in that post like a method receiver for *Movie.

Consider this example: https://play.golang.org/p/SZb47MKIr3

It'll fail to compile because the "Print" function has a **Pointer Receiver**, but the instances in the map are not pointers.

Whereas this example: https://play.golang.org/p/g0aXXcze5d Runs fine.

This is a good post explaining the difference: https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/08/09/dont-get-bitten-by-pointer-vs-non-pointer-method-receivers-in-golang/